# convert oracle date format based on user input

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle form that the user  loads data. The date format the user uses is different than what I have in my list of values. Need help in adding this format

```
SELECT
  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( 'Sunday, November 4, 2018', 'DD MON YYYY' ))
FROM
  DUAL;
```

Convert to `'11/4/2018'`.

[image: user date format]

Comment: All of the date/time format model elements are helpfully [listed in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-49B32A81-0904-433E-B7FE-51606672183A). Why are you converting the date back to a string - and why aren't you supplying a format model for that conversion? You're relying on the NLS session settings which is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert a *string* like `'Sunday, November 4, 2018'` to a `DATE` datatype with this expression:

```
TO_DATE( 'Sunday, November 4, 2018', 'Day, Month DD, YYYY' )
```

Then it is possible to convert the *date* to a *string* in another format with `TO_CHAR()`.

You seem to be looking for:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE( 'Sunday, November 4, 2018', 'Day, Month DD, YYYY' ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
FROM DUAL;
```

This yields:

```
11/04/2018
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4f08a5bc16e374fe3710d78c8219b5b7)**

Comment: Oracle disregards the mismatched placement of commas and the mismatched case, but it's still a good practice to be consistent. The format model should be `'Day, Month DD, YYYY'`.

Comment: @mathguy: ah yes good point. I tested without the comma and it worked, but yes, it is better to be consistent. Answer updated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped.

Comment: @heart1possible: welcome! If my answer properly responded to your question, please accept it by clicking the green check sign... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for the help